# Temporarily Disable All Email Delivery For Only One Contact

Tags: email

Is there a way to temporarily disable sending any email at all for just one Contact (Lead, PersonAccount) that behaves the same way as Email Deliverability = No Access does? That is: any automated or manual, declarative or API attempt to send an email to that Contact  will be blocked. [Help & Training isn't clear](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_opting_out_considerations.htm&type=5) on the extent of Email Opt Out = True

Comment: Set the Contact Email field to null? (You can obviously keep the address in a separate field so you can "re-enable" easily).

Comment: or append ".invalid" to it.

Comment: Certainly possible solutions although I was hoping to find one that does not falsify any data since that change itself could trigger other events.